# Magento blank table in Sales -> Orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.8

In the Magento back-end no table is showing up under Sales -> Orders. All other pages function normal.

[image: Blank Orders-page in Magento]

I re-installed the newest version of Magento, did a database repair (db-repair-tool) without results and disabled all non-Mage modules.
Mysql isn't returning errors, as well PHP isn't.

Comment: The table sales_flat_order in the Mysql database is filled!

Answer (score -2):

Clearing `/app/code/local` did the trick!

Comment: Your solution wasn't a good one. Some code into local folder was overwriting the grid and probably issuing a error. That was the reason why you weren't able to see the sales.

Comment: That is right. I thought, incorrectly, that disabling a module in the back-end caused Magento to bypass this folders.